# Finding specific data fields in worksheets that are different every time

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to collate values from multiple spread sheets I am given. Unfortunately the fields I am interested in are never in the same location, and can have any number of blank cells in between the value I want and the corresponding reference number (that identifies it as the number I want). They are always in the same row as each other though.

For example, I need to find all values that relate to '1. Number of people'. In worksheet 1 '1. Number of people' is in cell B2 and the value is in cell B6. In worksheet 2 these are in C4 and C7 respectively.

I am using 'find' to assign the location of '1. Number of people' to a range, but getting stuck after that.
I think I need to activate that cell, then offset until I find the next non blank cell and select that to copy, but can't work out how to do this.

So far all I have is:

```
Dim rgFound As Range

Set rgFound = Range("A1:E6").Find("1.Number of people", lookat:=xlWhole)
```

You can see I have not got very far!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can find the next non-blank cell with "rgFound.End(xlToRight)" assuming that the cell you need is the first non-blank cell.

Comment: Thank you! Very useful. It's been ages since I've done this, and it's slowly coming back to me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot.

```
Dim rgFound As Range
Set rgFound = Range("A1:E6").Find("1.Number of people", lookat:=xlWhole)

Dim rgValue as Range

If Not rgFound is Nothing Then 
    If Len(rgFound.Offset(1)) Then 'if the very next row is the next non-blank cell
        Set rgValue = rgFound.Offset(1) 
    Else 'if blanks appear between found and value
        Set rgValue = rgFound.End(xlDown)
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Thank you! I had also forgotten that I could use 'Not', which is very helpful!